# Multiple gateways with one ethernet adapter

Tags: networking, ethernet

I want to connect to multiple gateways with one ethernet adapter, this is how I tried to do it.

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# This is my home network.
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.102
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

# This is an external address, configuration works when placed at eth0.
auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
    address 132.45.65.60
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 132.45.65.57
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

I want to use eth0 as default internet connection and eth0:1 for specific services, like nginx.

```
server {
    listen 132.45.65.60:8080;
    server_name _;
    location / {
        return 403;
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this, and is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

First thing then you do is to set priority of you default gw route.
You can do this with adding a metric to route. You can do manually

```
sudo route add -net default gw 132.45.65.57 netmask 0.0.0.0 dev eth0:1 metric 10
```

or, you can write code to do this for you

```
sudo nano /etc/networking/interfaces
```

add at the end of interface configuration, but in the config of `eth0:1` interface

```
up route add default gw 132.45.65.57 metric 10
down route del default gw 132.45.65.57
```

Some thing like this

```
auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
     address 132.45.65.60
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     gateway 132.45.65.57
     dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
     up route add default gw 132.45.65.57 metric 10
     down route del default gw 132.45.65.57
```

After this you must mark packet and routing marked packet via eth0:1

I give you example to route traffic for source `port 8080` and you can implement for port you need for

Let’s start from the `iptables`. Here we shall take `8080` as the service for routing. Use `mangle` table of iptables for modifying the `8080` packets.

```
  sudo iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp –sport 8080 -j MARK –set-mark 0×1
```

We are marking all packets with source port `8080` as ’0×1′ .

Now save and restart `iptables`.

```
service iptables save
service iptables restart
```

To delete this entry from `iptables` we can use `-D` instead of `-A`.

Next, create a new IP route table in `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` by just giving an entry

```
100 8080table
```

Write rule for `8080` packets.

```
ip rule add fwmark 0×1 lookup 8080table
```

Add route at new table `8080table`. Here we shall use ’132.45.65.57′ as the gateway for `8080`. Address ’132.45.65.57′, in this example will be gateway address for `eth0:1` All other traffic will go through the
default gateway aka `eth0`, which can be seen by IP route show command.

We copy all entries except default gateway entry from main table.

```
 sudo ip route show table main | grep -Ev ^default | while read ROUTE ; do ip route add table 8080table $ROUTE; done
```

Add default gateway entry for `8080` packets to table `8080table`

```
  sudo ip route add default via 132.45.65.57 table 8080table
```

Use `ip route show table 8080table` to show all routes at `8080table`.

That’s it.

*Edit 1*

Maybe is better to mark and route traffic based on source route

```
auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
     address 132.45.65.60
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     gateway 132.45.65.57
     dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
     up route add default gw 132.45.65.57 metric 10
     down route del default gw 132.45.65.57
```

After this you must mark packet and routing marked packet via eth0:1

I give you example to route traffic based on ip, source `ip 132.45.65.60`

Again use `mangle` table of `iptables` for modifying the packets from `132.45.65.60`

```
  sudo iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -s 132.45.65.60 -j MARK -set-mark 0×1
```

We are marking all packets with source ip `132.45.65.60` as ’0×1′ .

Now save and restart `iptables`.

```
service iptables save
service iptables restart
```

To delete this entry from `iptables` we can use `-D` instead of `-A`.

Next, create a new IP route table in `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` by just giving an entry

```
100 132table
```

Write rule for  packets from source ip 132.45.65.60

```
ip rule add fwmark 0×1 lookup 132table
```

Add route at new table `132table`. Here we shall use ’132.45.65.57′ as the gateway for `132.45.65.60`. Address ’132.45.65.57′, in this example will be gateway address for `eth0:1` All other traffic will go through the
default gateway aka `eth0`, which can be seen by IP route show command.

We copy all entries except default gateway entry from main table.

```
 sudo ip route show table main | grep -Ev ^default | while read ROUTE ; do ip route add table 132table $ROUTE; done
```

Add default gateway entry for `132.45.65.60` packets to table `132table`

```
  sudo ip route add default via 132.45.65.57 table 132table
```

Use `ip route show table 132table` to show all routes at `132table`.

Comment: You have my *Edit 1* in answer, I thing is better to use source ip for mark and routing decision.

Comment: Thank you, but `sudo iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT –s 132.45.65.60 -j MARK –set-mark 0x1` gives `Bad argument `–s'` and I can't find where you use port 8080 in your edit.

Comment: I correct text formatting. Before s in command now is - , before was line. Also Edit 1 make rule based on source ip, not port.